# What is the difference between an autoencoder and an encoder-decoder?

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder

I want to know if there is a difference between an autoencoder and an encoder-decoder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Auto Encoders are a special case of encoder-decoder models.  In the case of auto encoders, the input and the output domains are the same ( typically ). The Wikipedia page for Autoencoder, mentions,

> The simplest way to perform the copying task perfectly would be to
> duplicate the signal. Instead, autoencoders are typically forced to
> reconstruct the input approximately, preserving only the most relevant
> aspects of the data in the copy.

For instance, they are used for denoising data. The inputs for such a model are the noisy inputs and the outputs are the denoised inputs. You can find an [example](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) here.

Encoder-Decoder models can also have different input and output domains, like in the case of [neural machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_machine_translation). The inputs and the outputs have different domains, as they belong to two different languages and can have variable lengths as well.

Comment: Thank you , your answer was so helpful for me, thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the difference, instead providing a couple examples of where these architectures are used. Also, where are the quotes from? (The second quote makes no sense.)

Answer (score 10):

According to section 2.3 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05566.pdf) paper:

> Auto-encoders are special cases of encoder-decoder models in which the input and output are the same.

The same section of the paper describes encoder-decoder as follows:

> Encoder-Decoder models are a family of models which learn to map data-points from an input domain to an output domain via a two-stage network: The encoder, represented by an encoding function z = f(x), compresses the input into a latent-space representation; the decoder, y = g(z), aims to predict the output from the latent space representation.